# Android custom onBackPressed to OnBackPressedCallback

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have this custom back press:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (condition()) {
        doSomething()
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

I can't seem to find a way to make it a OnBackPressedCallback,

```
private fun setupBackPress() {
    onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(owner = this) {
        if (condition()) {
            doSomething()
        } else {
            onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed() 
            // I don't know what to do in this case, 
            // this here would be an infinite loop 
            // but I need to just make it like super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: This is the key difference between the old "just-in-time" model of checking a condition when back is pressed vs the "ahead-of-time" model where you need to set the `isEnabled` state on your callback when your `condition()` changes so that your callback is not enabled when `condition()` is false, automatically allowing the default behavior to happen. Where does your condition change?

Comment: in italy in that cases we use this expression: "simple business complications office"